# reorganizing my filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, fstab, gparted

I want to reorganize my file system. I have swap allocated that I don't use. My `/` partition is overflowing all the time, and because of that I've kept moving big directories to a separate partition `/mnt/nvme0n1p4`. It occurred to me that it might be smarter to move all those directories back to `/home` and mount `/home` from what is now `/mnt/nvme0n1p4`.

I would also like to extend `/` with the space now on `/nvme0n1p2`.

*I don't do this kind of stuff every day. So I thought that I should ask for some feedback on my plan.*

My plan is to do the following: **(I added some comments in bold after I actually executed my plan.)**

- copy the content of `/home` to `/mnt/nvme0n1p4`
- copy all directories on `/mnt/nvme0n1p4` that are now symlinked to from `/home` to their correct location `/mnt/nvme0n1p4/me`
- `sudo rm -rf /home/*`  <-- **Edited after @raj advice**
- `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /home`
- change the folowing line in `/etc/fstab`:

```bsh
UUID=aaf7e7e2-d36b-4877-b862-612d403a15da /mnt/nvme0n1p4 ext4    defaults,noatime 0 2
```

to

```bsh
UUID=aaf7e7e2-d36b-4877-b862-612d403a15da /home          ext4    defaults,noatime 0 2
```

- backup the content of `/` to somewhere on `/mnt/data`. Just in case.
- use gparted to remove `[SWAP]` and add it in front of `/`  <-- **Worked fine for me**
- Remove [SWAP] from `/etc/fstab` <-- **I forgot this step initially. Causing an error during booting. So I had to do this from an bootable usb.**
- finished?

#### some system info

```bsh
me@mypc $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931,5G  0 part /mnt/data
sdb           8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0 111,8G  0 part /opt
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    32G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 883,2G  0 part /mnt/nvme0n1p4

me@mypc $ df   
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              16G     0   16G   0% /dev
run              16G  1,7M   16G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3   32G   29G  1,3G  96% /
tmpfs            16G  324M   16G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4,0M     0  4,0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            16G   50M   16G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb1       110G   26G   79G  25% /opt
/dev/nvme0n1p4  869G  412G  413G  50% /mnt/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300M  312K  300M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       916G  113G  757G  13% /mnt/data
tmpfs           3,2G   56K  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000

me@mypc $ ls /mnt/nvme0n1p4 
 docker   Documents   Downloads   home   lost+found   R   Repos  'VirtualBox VMs'   VMs

me@mypc $ ls -l ~/.
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 me me  4096  5 dec 10:38 bin
drwxr-xr-x 9 me me  4096 20 dec 21:48 CytoscapeConfiguration
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    10  3 nov 16:03 Data -> /mnt/data/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    25  4 nov 09:55 Documents -> /mnt/nvme0n1p4/Documents/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    24  8 nov 00:36 Downloads -> /mnt/nvme0n1p4/Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 3 me me  4096 10 dec 23:16 igv
drwxr-xr-x 3 me me 12288 16 feb 15:57 Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    16 13 nov 09:41 R -> /mnt/nvme0n1p4/R
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    20  9 nov 14:06 Repos -> /mnt/nvme0n1p4/Repos
drwxr-xr-x 3 me me  4096  4 nov 08:14 snap
drwxr-xr-x 4 me me  4096 14 feb 20:22 tmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me     9  3 nov 16:58 Unsorted -> /mnt/tmp/
```

#### expected result

```bsh
me@mypc $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931,5G  0 part /mnt/data
sdb           8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0 111,8G  0 part /opt
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    48G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 883,2G  0 part /home
```

Comment: Can you show what symbolic links you have in `/home`? Do you only have links directly in `/home`, e.g. `/home/foo -> /mnt/nvme0n1p4/foo`? Are there any name conflicts between files or directories in `/home` and `/mnt/nvme0n1p4`?

Comment: yes, I added the info in the question. the directory that `~/me/Unsorted` points to is empty, so I will remove it. There are no other users with a home folder on this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically looks good, however:

- in step 3, instead of `rm -rf /home`, better do `rm -rf /home/*`. You should not remove the `/home` directory itself, only it's contents, because you need an **empty** `/home` directory to exist as a mount point. If you happen to delete the `/home` directory, you need to re-create it with the same ownership and permissions as the previous `/home` directory had.
- when performing steps 3 and 4, you should be out of the `/home` directory, ie. your current directory should be for example `/` or `/root`. It would be best to perform the whole operation being logged in directly as `root`, if it is possible in your system, in this way you won't use the `/home` directory at all.

I'm also not sure about extending the root partition with the space that is **before** that partition. (I guess that your `nvme0n1p2` is located before `nvme0n1p3` on the disk). While there is no issue with extending the partition and filesystem past the end of the partition, I'm not sure if the same applies for extending it before the start of the partition. I'm not sure if gparted/e2fstools is able to move the inode table and all filesystem structures backwards, towards the new start of the partition. Maybe there's someone more experienced with such changes who can answer that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll act on your two remarks and I'll wait for some feedback on the gparted issue.

Comment: Just a head up: Turns out, gparted can merge a root partitions with the partition in front of if.